# Kamba Ramayana with English Commentary

Tags: ramayana

I am interested to have an English Commentary on Kamba Ramayana with the original verses in Tamil. It may be a particular sitr, but I am interested in the same in form of a-book, priced or free.

Please give links.

Comment: Do you want translation or translation with commentary?

Comment: Well Tamil version you can have it here: https://archive.org/details/KambaRamayanamSundaraKandamVaiMuGo, english version can be found here: http://englishkambaramayanam.blogspot.ca/2014/04/kamba-ramayanam-bala-kandam-i.html

Comment: I am looking for Tamil verses with English Meaning and / or Commentary